# Data Scrape Search Limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am using a ruby seed file that scrapes data from APOD (Astronomy Picture of the Day). Since there are thousands of entries, is there a way to limit the scrape to just pull the past 365 images?

Here's the seed code I am using:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'curl'
require 'fileutils'

BASE = 'http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/'
FileUtils.mkdir('small') unless File.exist?('small')
FileUtils.mkdir('big') unless File.exist?('big')

f = open 'http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/archivepix.html'
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f.read)
html_doc.xpath('//b//a').each do |element|
    imgurl = BASE + element.attributes['href'].value
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(imgurl).read)
    doc.xpath('//p//a//img').each do |elem|
        small_img = BASE + elem.attributes['src'].value
        big_img = BASE + elem.parent.attributes['href'].value
        s_img_f = open("small/#{File.basename(small_img)}", 'wb')
        b_img_f = open("big/#{File.basename(big_img)}", 'wb')
        rs_img = Curl::Easy.new(small_img)
        rb_img = Curl::Easy.new(big_img)
        rs_img.perform
        s_img_f.write(rs_img.body_str) 
        rb_img.perform
        b_img_f.write(rb_img.body_str)
        s_img_f.close
        puts "Download #{File.basename(small_img)} finished."
        b_img_f.close
        puts "Download #{File.basename(big_img)} finished."
        rs_img.close
        rb_img.close
    end
end
puts "All done."
```

Comment: Why do you require OpenURI twice? It won't go any faster when you do that.

Comment: Accidentally copied that line twice when posting the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the node set like an array to get elements between a specific index.

Add `[0..364]` to the node set of links:

```
html_doc.xpath('//b//a')[0..364].each do |element|
```

Comment: `0..365` is 366 elements.